# How to edit MS Access database using C#

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010

I have found many posts on here which are relating to my issue however I am struggling to find out what exactly I need to change to solve my problem of updating an MS Access database from a C# application. So I apologize if people feel this post is too similar to others. Here is my update code:

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ConnString = (@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Ts\Documents\testDB.accdb");
    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection (ConnString))
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {      
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [Table4] SET [EmpName] = ?, [Age] = ?, [Mobile] = ?  WHERE [ID] = ?";

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = idtextBox1.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = nametextBox2.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = agetextBox3.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = mobiletextBox4.Text;
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        conn.Open();

        int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.Close();
        Form1_Load(sender, e);
        MessageBox.Show("record updated ");
    }
}
```

Comment: this question doesn't have enough information on exactly what you are trying to do, what is happening / any errors.  Your code shouldn't have commented out sections, you should keep it to the very minimum you can

Comment: @KeithNicholas Please stop editing the OP's code.

Comment: @GSerg  sorry, no. commented out code has no place in a code example

Comment: @KeithNicholas It shows what alternatives they are trying. Even if it did not, regardless of how bad the code is, it is never to be edited, only formatted.

Comment: @GSerg that isn't a rule.

Answer (score 3):

For OleDb the order of parameters is of paramount importance. The reason your update will not work, is that you are supplying the ID parameter first, whereas in your SQL it is last (comes in the `WHERE` clause). Move this parameter to the end and it should work.

The revised code should be something like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ConnString = (@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Ts\Documents\testDB.accdb");
    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnString))
    {
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [Table4] SET [EmpName] = ?, [Age] = ?, [Mobile] = ?  WHERE [ID] = ?";

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = nametextBox2.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = agetextBox3.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = mobiletextBox4.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = idtextBox1.Text;
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();

            int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    Form1_Load(sender, e);
    MessageBox.Show("record updated ");
}
```

I have made a couple of other minor changes, most importantly moving the `Form1_Load` and the `MessageBox` outside of the `using` block.  In general you should keep code within `using` blocks to a minimum, so that the resources can be freed as soon as possible.  I also removed the `Close()`.  The `OleDbConnection`'s destructor automatically calls `Close()`, so there is no specific need to call it yourself.

One other thing might be wrong.  You have the ID as a `varchar`.  Are you sure about this?  It would be more usual if it were an integer.  In which case, you would need to parse the idTextBox1.Text to an integer with `int.Parse()`, or safer with `int.TryParse()`, and change the parameter type as well.

Comment: @KeithNicholas Good idea.  I've updated the answer. Thanks